# black gooey stuff in gas tank

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I just bought a  01 vt600 vlx and i noticed there is some black gooey tar looking stuff all over the outside bottom of the carburator so I looked inside the tank and there is alot of the same stuff all in the bottom of the tank any ideas what this could be? could it have anything to do with ethanol gas ? the last owner said he used 10% ethanol gas in it . the bike only has 2000 miles on it . the pic i added of the inside of the take realy dosent show the bottom of the take where it is thick [image][image]

Comment: looks more like rust, try carb cleaner